# Ubuntu 20.04 freezing randomly on laptop?

Tags: nautilus, laptop, ssd, freeze

Hey I installed ubuntu 20.04LTS in my nvme ssd. I also have an auto-mounting hard drive for personal data and games. My kernel is the latest available on ubuntu (5.4 low latency).
The system works fine but once in a while it crashes, and it does not respond at all (no mouse, no keyboard, the display freezes totally, so the only way to make it respond is hard reset). Also I think it could be a nautilus error since I looked on the internet. My system log shows the following message just before the system freezes, but i'm not shure if a single app can freeze the whole computer to the point to make it freeze:

"alled "net usershare info" but it failed: Falló al ejecutar el proceso hijo «net» (No such file or directory)" (my language is spanish)

This happened in the last 2 crashes, the first one when actually using nautilus and the second one watching youtube on firefox (the video just stopped, no image nor audio). I don't know what could be causing this problem.

Also I did have ubuntu installed on my hard drive before installing this ssd, the problem begun with this installation, the hard drive was wiped and formatted (ext4) and now the system is booting from the nvme ssd. Before this installation the computer was running flawlessly on the hard drive.

My specs:
Laptop model: Lenovo Ideapad S340 14API
AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega 8 graphics (MESA latest drivers)
SSD nvme 250GB
1TB HDD
8GB RAM single channel

Please help